# Latest Emacs Version, Windowed GUI

Tags: latex, emacs

I am having an issue with GNU Emacs 24.3.1. I usually only use emacs for the purpose of compiling .pdf or LaTeX documents. And I am unable to open the program correctly via terminal use. I initially type something like the following:

```
emacs foo.tex &
```

The window will appear but not in the normal buffer. It only appears in the *scratch* buffer. Contrary to this if I type something like:

```
sudo emacs foo.tex &
```

I will get the correct buffer in my window but I get an error message that looks like:

```
(emacs: 3859): GLib-Warning **: In call to g_spawn_sync(), exit status of child process....
```

I will attach the full error message if needed. I am wondering if it is possible that I may have incorrectly installed emacs. Any advice would be appreciated if anyone is familiar with this sort of issue. Thank you!

EDIT: The output of:

```
 type emacs
```

is as follows:

```
 emacs is hashed (/usr/bin/emacs)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `type emacs` to your question.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch I added it per your request. I hope it helps!

Comment: Looks good. In Emacs what's the value of `initial-buffer-choice
`? You can get that for example with `M-: initial-buffer-choice`

Comment: @FlorianDiesch initial-buffer-choice in sudo emacs gives a value of 'nil', in emacs *scratch* it gives 'nil' as well.

Comment: Try to remove all Emacs config files. If that doesn't help I don't have any other idea ...

Comment: @FlorianDiesch So I went through a very long process of attempting to remove all emacs config files, then initialization files, then just all the files in general. Went through and re-installed it, it was to no avail. However, after several hours I found the solution, and I thought you or anyone else on here should know.

The '~/.emacs.d/' file was not under my user ownership, it was under root ownership, so I change the permissions using:

'sudo chown -R user ~/.emacs.d/'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was that I as the user did not have ownership of the

```
~/emacs.d/
```

folder, so I type in the following command to solve it:

```
sudo chown -R user ~/.emacs.d/
```

However the GLib-Warning with the sudo emacs is a bug in emacs that hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Further, in future when using emacs with sudo, use `-H`: `sudo -H emacs`. This sets `$HOME` to root's , so that files in your home directory are not affected.

Comment: @muru Thank you for the advice I will keep that in mind!